# Generate pivot table: Error ORA-00918

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot-table

I am trying to create a pivort table for these 200 words. Below is my code, and SQL keeps giving me an error message `Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"`. The error points to `SELECT *`.

However, when I cut the word list from 200 to the first 3, it will generate the table but give me this error `Error report:
SQL Command: table FINAL_PIVOTTEST
Failed: Warning: execution completed with warning`. Appreciate your help!

```
    CREATE TABLE FINAL_PIVOTTEST AS;
    SELECT *
    FROM 
    (SELECT QUESID, WORD FROM FINAL_WORDLIST)
    PIVOT 
    (COUNT (WORD)
    FOR WORD IN (
    'article',
    'color',
    'icard',
    'icard',
    '400',
    'link',
    'stroke',
    'resume',
    'theories',
    'floppy',
    'semester',
    'justice',
    'rent',
    'receipt',
    'idnr',
    'bronze',
    'govdocument',
    'room',
    'means',
    'roomreservation',
    'checkout',
    'soil',
    'tour',
    'money',
    'grainger',
    'putting',
    'union',
    'microfiche',
    'disappeared',
    'explored',
    'returning',
    'returning',
    'replacement',
    'password',
    'homepage',
    'paper',
    'games',
    '1970s',
    'british',
    'board',
    'side',
    'leave',
    'electronically',
    'conversation',
    'message',
    'park',
    'next',
    '2013',
    'isnt',
    'today',
    'option',
    'citing',
    'job',
    'chemistry',
    'tomorrow',
    'citation ',
    'never',
    'availability',
    'availability',
    'mainstx',
    'mainstx',
    'personal',
    'alumni',
    'alumni',
    'test',
    'period',
    'undergraduate',
'medical',
'textbooks',
'missing',
'reserve',
'later',
'later',
'development',
'user',
'movie',
'visiting',
'refworks',
'refworks',
'talk',
'shelf',
'sciences',
'chapter',
'too',
'those',
'ebook',
'building',
'call',
'desk',
'wondered',
'scientist',
'during',
'ugl',
'ugl',
'ugl',
'problems',
'book',
'address',
'system',
'listed',
'location',
'free',
'site',
'bis',
'various',
'software',
'chat',
'phone',
'process',
'documenT',
'pdf',
'author',
'general',
'american',
'copies',
'newspaper',
'located',
'requested',
'particular',
'called',
'called',
'report',
'faculty',
'sshel',
'graduate',
'public',
'public',
'check',
'member'));
```

The table I am using to generate this pivot table looks like this:

```
READSCALE   QUESID     SENTID    WORDID    WORD
  2         a00001       1         1       book
  3         a00002       1         2      library
 ...         ...        ...       ...       ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list of words to pivot includes duplicates - since you are instructing the database to turn each word in the IN () statement into a column name, you are receiving an error because you are trying to create a table with multiple columns of the same name.

Instead, use the following code (make sure I got all the words correctly):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(SELECT QUESID, WORD FROM FINAL_WORDLIST)
PIVOT 
(COUNT (WORD)
FOR WORD IN    
  (
    'fire',
    'dnr',
    'relay',
    'techloan',
    'calculator',
    'purse',
    'owner',
    'botanical',
    'chatted',
    'book',
    'safe',
    'serial',
    'decisions',
    'interviewing',
    'headphones',
    'keys',
    'sd',
    'prospective',
    'hr',
    'caller',
    'undergraduate',
    'directional',
    'habits',
    'discharge',
    'donating',
    'receipt',
    'bronze',
    'color',
    'addresses',
    'individuals',
    'tablet',
    'stations',
    'istc',
    'soil',
    'acquisition',
    'hiring',
    'retiree',
    'archival',
    'potential',
    'renewals',
    'release',
    'notes',
    'chapter',
    'camera',
    'apply',
    'discussion',
    'return',
    'provide',
    'sdc',
    'brief',
    'tour',
    'future',
    'mediacenter',
    'interview',
    'librarians',
    'courtesy',
    'overdue',
    'session',
    'message',
    'reports',
    'lib',
    'emailed',
    'numbers',
    'alumni',
    'printer',
    'building',
    'show',
    'recent',
    'returned',
    'availability',
    'talk',
    'scan',
    'job',
    'renew',
    'order',
    'scientist',
    'oakstr',
    'digital',
    'room',
    'reading',
    'media',
    'circ',
    'video',
    'call',
    'list',
    'open',
    'dvd',
    'lost',
    'card',
    'google',
    'graduate',
    'scanner',
    'phone',
    'policies',
    'before',
    'reserves',
    'called',
    'computer',
    'working',
    'location',
    'another',
    'full',
    'callnumber',
    'staff',
    'email',
    'collection',
    'campus',
    'showed',
    'checked',
    'contact',
    'research',
    'ugl',
    'ill',
    'item',
    'print',
    'journal',
    'request',
    'books',
    'library'
  )
);
```

Click here for [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0631/3)

Comment: It's still not working. I can create a pivot with the first word, but not working for the whole list.

Comment: Try going through your list of words and removing them in smaller chunks, so you can isolate exactly when/where a certain word is causing your query to fail.  Comment out half the words and see if it will run: if it runs, you know those words are OK and if not, you know that one or more of those is the problem.

Comment: The problem was that there were repeated words. Pivot table does not take them. I removed these words to get the tale work. This would technically work, not sure if it would impact the calculation results though. All the repeating words have the same information gain value...

Comment: if you really need the fields to show up multiple times (i.e., on a report) you could select that column several different times in your top SELECT statement. the caclulations themselves, however should not change - each one will count all occurences of that word.

Answer (score 1):

Try by specifying the the aliases for each value inside your IN, as well as for the COUNT(word) :

```
 CREATE TABLE FINAL_PIVOTTEST AS
 SELECT *
 FROM 
 (SELECT QUESID, WORD FROM FINAL_WORDLIST)
 PIVOT 
 (COUNT (WORD) wrd
 FOR WORD IN ('fire' as fire,
 'dnr' as dnr
 ..............
```